# How do I generate the set of binary strings with elements that are unique under reversal?

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

What is the most efficient way to generate the set $S$ of unique binary strings of a certain length, $L$, s.t. all strings are unique under the reversal operation?  For example, if $L = 2$, the elements of $S$ would be {00, 01, 11}.  Also, what is $||S||$ as a function of $L$?

Comment: What does "all strings are unique under the reversal operation" mean?

Comment: @William Chan, Take the set of all unique binary strings of a certain length, and then prune this list of strings s.t. one has the largest possible subset where no two strings are equivalent even if one is allowed to reflect/reverse any binary sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate all strings of length $L$ and discard those that are lexicographically greater than their reverse.

This number of strings this produces is $2^L$ minus half of the number of strings that are *not* palindromes. There are $2^{\lceil L/2 \rceil}$ palindromes, so
$$|S| = 2^L - \frac{2^L - 2^{\lceil L/2\rceil}}{2} =
2^{L-1} + 2^{\lceil L/2\rceil-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

For every string $x$,

- If $x$ is a palindrome ($x = x^R$), pick it.
- Otherwise, pick either $x$ or $x^{R}$, but not both.

The maximum size of $S$ is
$$
\frac{2^L - P}{2} + P = \frac{2^L+P}{2},
$$ 
where $P$ is the number of palindromes of length $L$. Can you see why $P$ is equal to
$$
2^{\lceil \frac{L}{2} \rceil}?
$$